# ActionListener can't resolve a component

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am using window builder to build a simple test GUI

However, I am running into a problem.

I am trying to append text to a text area component via an ActionListener attached to a button. However, when I write in the line, it says

> textArea cannot be resolved

**I have marked the areas in question with comments**

```
public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 457, 435);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 149, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 14, 0, 307, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_separator = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_separator.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_separator.gridx = 1;
        gbc_separator.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator, gbc_separator);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_separator_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_separator_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_separator_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_separator_1.gridy = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1, gbc_separator_1);

        //Here is the button.

        JButton btnBeginScan = new JButton("Begin Scan");
        btnBeginScan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //This is where I get the error.
                textArea.append("hello");
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnBeginScan = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnBeginScan.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btnBeginScan.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnBeginScan.gridy = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBeginScan, gbc_btnBeginScan);

        Choice choice = new Choice();
        choice.setBackground(SystemColor.scrollbar);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_choice = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_choice.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_choice.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_choice.gridx = 1;
        gbc_choice.gridy = 2;
        frame.getContentPane().add(choice, gbc_choice);

        //This is the text area. 

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Source Sans Pro Light", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textArea.gridy = 3;
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea, gbc_textArea);

        JButton btnCancelScan = new JButton("Cancel Scan");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnCancelScan = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnCancelScan.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnCancelScan.gridy = 4;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCancelScan, gbc_btnCancelScan);
    }

}
```

I am very new to building guis in java, all I know is through online tutorials. I tried searching my problem, but I didn't quite understand the answers, or maybe I wasn't asking the right question. Which is why I have come here to ask this.

Comment: Have you tried to move button definition after the `textArea`?

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of your text area before the part of your code where you have the action listener which manipulates it, otherwise the compiler will not know that variable `textArea` exists when processing the listener code and you will get the *Cannot resolve symbol* error.

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
// ...

btnBeginScan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        textArea.append("hello");
    }
});
```

Also if you use Java 7 or lower, the `textArea` variable must be declared as `final` in order for it to be accessible in the anonymous `ActionListener`. In Java 8 `final` would not be necessary in this case, since `textArea` variable is [*effectively final*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

> A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.